# Google Drive API V3 - Copy function not copying contents

Tags: google-drive-api

I've been working on a project to 'duplicate' a Team Drive. I've got the application successfully recreating the entire drive structure and copying files who's mimetype is *not* a Google folder. My issue is that the contents of copied files are not being copied as well.

I'm using Node for the application, with the Google Drive API SDK.

```js
await drive
      .files
      .copy({
        fileId: file.id,
        supportsAllDrives: true,
        requestBody: {
          name: Mustache.render(originalFile.name, data),
          driveId: driveId,
          parents: [
            parentId
          ],
          mimeType: originalFile.mimeType
        }
      })
      .then(res => {
        newFile = res.data;
      })
      .catch(e => {
        logger.error("Issue copying a file: ", e);
      });
```

So while the above functions as expected (adjusting the name of the new file, putting it in the correct parent folder, under the correct new drive ID), there is *no* content in these copied files.

For a more specific example, let's say that one of the files I'm copying is a PDF. The new PDF with the correct mimetype shows in my new Team Drive, but when opening it (in browser, or downloading), there's nothing at all there. See some screenshots for what I mean.

Original Drive and file, note the size:
[image: Original with size and content]

New Drive file, with no size/content:
[image: Copy with no size or content]

Edit1:
I tried using the API explorer as a proof of concept again. It works as expected, copying the content. Tried it twice, first to the same folder in the same Team drive, then created a new team drive with a subfolder. Content copied fine in both cases.

[image: Example body from API Explorer]

In the case that it matters, here's the request for creating the new drive as well. `requestId` is just a random guid using the [Chance repo](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chance).

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The only error source I can imagine is `mimeType`

You do not need to specify the `mimeType` if you only want to copy a file without converting it.

Try a simple request without the request body:

```js
drive.files.copy(
  {
    fileId: file.id,
    requestBody: {}
  },
  (err, res) => {
    if (err) return console.log(("Issue copying a file: " + err);
    newFile = res.data;
    console.log(newFile);  
  }
);
```

Once you confirm that it works correctly, add parameters one by one.

Comment: Are you sure the file wsa not empty before copying? Test with the [try this API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/copy).

Comment: Oh for sure. Didn't want to do a screenshot of the content of one of the PDFs, but did open it prior to the copy. The size of the file is what I was hoping to use as confirmation

Comment: But, using the API explorer, yes the content gets copied. I'll add a comment to my post showing the body used in the API explorer, which is the same body I'm using in the app.

Comment: Sounds then like there is an error in your code. Is the error being caught? Try to implement more logs for troubleshooting.

Comment: Ya will do right now. This'll probably be one of those things where my brain just didn't start up well enough in the morning.

Comment: Ya I think you made me logic my way through it. Had an if/else that wasn't evaluating correctly, meaning I was always creating a new file, and not using the copy function. Worked that out and now got a user permissions error, but I think I'll work that separately. Gonna mark you the winner and close this one out :-)